# Django: for loop and if condition in one line

Tags: python, django

I want to bring `if dynamic_tickets:` and `for ticket in dynamic_tickets:` in one line. I always receive a syntax error. Do you have an idea, how to achieve that?

```
def adjust_prices():
    events = Event.objects.filter(status=EventStatus.LIVE)
    active_events = [event for event in events if not event.is_over]

    for active_event in active_events:
        dynamic_tickets = [
            ticket for ticket in active_event.tickets.all() if ticket.dynamic_pricing_activated()
        ]
        if dynamic_tickets:
            for ticket in dynamic_tickets:
                print(ticket)
                print("DO OTHER STUFF")
```

Comment: *I always receive a syntax error.* What error do you get? and on what line?

Comment: I think OP is asking for the python equivalent of the JS `array && array.forEach()`

Comment: to solve this error you must add stack trace of raised exception

Comment: What I see when I try `for ticket in dynamic_tickets if dynamic_tickets:` is that message in my console `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: you can only use `for ticket in dynamic_tickets if ticket` but not `for ticket in dynamic_tickets if dynamic_tickets`. there's no need to write a list comprehension for the second one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need to use 'if dynamic_tickets:' , because when the list 'dynamic_tickets' will not be empty then only for loop will execute.
just write the code like this:

```
def adjust_prices():
    events = Event.objects.filter(status=EventStatus.LIVE)
    active_events = [event for event in events if not event.is_over]

    for active_event in active_events:
        dynamic_tickets = [
            ticket for ticket in active_event.tickets.all() if 
            ticket.dynamic_pricing_activated()
           ]

        for ticket in dynamic_tickets:
            print(ticket)
            print("DO OTHER STUFF")
```